# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): while using facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, react-native

[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW7ny.png) React Native:

> Possible unhandled promise rejection while using fbsdk

It displays a yellow screen with the above error. i tried lot to debug this but dint worked kindly Please help me to debug this error.

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import FBSDK, { LoginManager } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

export default class fbappss extends Component {


   _fbAuth(){

        LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile']).then(function(result){

          if (result.isCancelled) {

              console.log('Login was cancelled'); 
          } else {

              console.log('Login was a success' + result.grantedPermission.toString());
          }
        }, function(error) {

            console.log('an error occured:' +error);
        })

        }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._fbAuth()}>
        <Text>facebook</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('fbappss', () => fbappss);
```

Comment: on should be written like onPress={()=>this._fbAuth()} otherwise it will execute while rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your error page

Try rebuilding your project after placing FDSDK in right place